# HTML ComboBox value to e-mail

Tags: html, css, combobox, html-email

My mate and i are making a website using Wix.com website builder, and its going alright, although, i wanted to make a combo box where the user of our website is going to set his iPhone's conditions, so we can estimate its value. However, i cannot figure out how to get the chosen value of a couple of different combo boxes in the same html object into an e-mail, which will then be sent to us.
Im not very good at html (i literally started learning it yesterday), but googling some different things, ive created this small thing, resulting in a fancy combo box. Heres the code ive come up with: (Wix does not accept html and css, but only inline html, so it might seem a bit complicated)

```
<html style="background:none; text-align:center; padding:0px 0;"><body style="background:none; text-align:center; padding:0px 0;"> <label style="position:relative">
    <select style="font-size: 17px;
        padding:2px;
        margin:0;
        border-radius:4px;
        width:160px;
        box-shadow:0 1px 0 #EF6423, 0 -1px #EF6423 inset;
        background:FFFFFF;
        color:#4B4B4B;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#EF6423;
        outline:none;display:inline-block;
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        padding-right:18px;">
        <option selected> iPhone stand</option>
        <option>Helt ny</option>
        <option>Som ny</option>
        <option>Udm&aelig;rket</option>
        <option>Slidt</option>
        <option>Defekt</option></select></label> </body></html>

<html><body><arrows style='font-size: 50px;    font:14px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:#8A8A8A;    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(11px, -4px);
    transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0px,-3px);
    right:8px; top:2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;'>
    <> </arrows></body></html>
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using an HTML form in email is unreliable. Major email clients (namely Outlook) do not allow this and remove functionality. Unless you have the analytics to show this is worth the risk, I would not recommend it.

Secondly, a large majority of the great things you can do in HTML forms is kaput in HTML email. So even if you were able to put a form in the email, I still think it would be overall cleaner and easier to just link to a landing page or survey site (e.g. survey monkey) and gather the info there. That way you can have full control based on web standards instead of flakey 1990 email HTML.

**On second glance reading this - if you only have one question for your form, just make each option a link or button to a submission page using parameters to carry over the information to the page and then you have something close to same functionality as what you were looking for without the headache

Comment: Hmm, that sounds a hell of a lot easier than what i would have done. I think im going to do the last option you mentioned and take them to another page, where they then fill in some information. Thank you for the answer :)